# MVC-How to Join Two Tables or Models using Linq ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am working with **asp.NET MVC**. And I am trying to find Salary Grades of employees [as we find in oracle 12c using scott schema]. I have created 4 Models ***EMP, DEPT, Bonus, and SalGrade (Same as scott schema in oracle 12c)***. The query for finding grades in Oracle-12c is following.

```
SELECT s.grade, count(*), max(sal)
 FROM EMP e, SalGrade s
   WHERE e.sal BETWEEN s.LoSal AND s.HiSal
     GROUP BY s.grade;
```

***I just need to convert the above given query into ASP.NET MVC LINQ query.***

Models I have created are follwing.

**Dept Models:**

```
public class Department{
[Key]
public int Deptno { get; set; }
public string Dname { get; set; }
public string  Loc { get; set; }}
```

**EMP Model:**

```
 public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int Empno { get; set; }
    public string  Ename { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
    public int Mgr { get; set; }
    public DateTime Hiredate { get; set; }
    public int Sal { get; set; }
    public int Comm { get; set; }
    public int Deptno { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }

}
```

**SalGrade Model**

```
public class Salgrade
{
    [Key]
    public int Grade { get; set; }
    public int LoSal { get; set; }
    public int HiSal { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller class method, you might have some code like this:

```
using(var db = new DepartmentEntities()){

    var query = from db.Employee, db.Salgrade
                where db.Employee.Sal between db.Salgrade.LoSal and db.Salgrade.HiSal
                group by db.Salgrade.Grade
                select new { db.Salgrade.Grade, count(*), max(db.Employee.Sal) };

    // Use query results in a foreach loop or whatever...
}
```